# Como imprimir uma informação que esteja no formato json mas que seja impresso de uma forma que dê para o usuário ler?

Tags: java, json

A aplicação está imprimindo neste formato json mas eu nao quero que imprima assim.
Por exemplo eu só quero que imprima  "translation": "Oi querida" e só. estou utilizando eclipse e a linguagem de servidor java, como faz?

Estou utilizando uma API mas preciso mostrar os dados que recebo dessa api quando eu coloco para imprimir com System.out.println(resultado);

Está imprimindo dessa forma:

```
 {
   "character_count": 8,
  "translations": [
{
  "translation": "Oi querida"
}
],
 "word_count": 2
}
```

Comment: me ajuda, por favor.

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Não negativei, vc precisa converter essa string em um hashmap ou outra estrutura/tipo e aí manipular ele. coloque o código que tem.

Comment: A pergunta soa como "façam pra mim a conversão desse json". Adicione o que já tentou, e, como o @rray disse, defina um titulo mais objetivo ao problema.

Comment: não consegui fazer isso ainda......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a melhor forma para fazer isso seria estruturar essa sua string JSON, ou seja incluir ela em alguma estrutura de dados para conseguir acessar/modificar seus valores de forma mais simples, para isso eu usaria uma biblioteca para transformar uma String JSON em um objeto, sendo este por exemplo um Mapa ou um próprio objeto seu para representa esse JSON, segue uma biblioteca mais código de referencia para você utilizar que iria resolver esse problema.

O nome da biblioteca é Gson, ela é mantida pelo google, e é bem popular no mundo Java.

## Codigo de exemplo:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = "{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\"}";
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
System.out.println(map.get("k1")); //Saida = v1
```

### Referencias.

#### Repositorio no github: https://github.com/google/gson

#### Documentação: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: no meu retorna null.

Comment: provavelmente seu json está invalido ou sem os caracteres de escape. 

Usa esse site http://jsonlint.com/ para validar o seu JSON e coloca os caracters de escape que nem eu coloquei ali no exemplo.

Depois se ainda der problema me manda o JSON.

Comment: Opa eu consegui.

Comment: Show cara, bons estudos ai :)